# Why does getIntent().getData() returns null for getIntent() actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE?

Tags: android, app-actions, google-assistant

I mechanically copied the code from [Google's official document](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature) to test integrating Google Assistant actions with an app:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- This is a sample actions.xml -->
  <actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
      <!-- Use url from inventory match for deep link fulfillment -->
      <fulfillment urlTemplate="{@url}" />


      <!-- Define parameters with inventories here -->
      <parameter name="feature">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet"/>
      </parameter>
    </action>

    <entity-set entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet">
      <!-- Provide a URL per entity -->
      <entity url="myapp://deeplink/one" name="featureParam_one"/>
      <entity url="myapp://deeplink/two" name="featureParam_two"/>
    </entity-set>
  </actions>
```

The above is the content of actions.xml.  App Actions Test Tool is happy with it.  When I click Run, the app is opened, but getIntent().getData() returns null.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how it works. If you click run you just launch your app. To get data from the intent app should be launched from Google Assistant or link.

Comment: Do you mean the App Actions Test Tool does not simulate Google Assistant and it is just another way of starting the app?

Comment: Sorry, but I misunderstood the 'Run' term. The test tool is starting google assistant which starts our app (you can see this in ADB Command on the left from button Run). Show the activity declaration which should handle intent in your manifest, please.